# Run NetBeans java project by windows command prompt

Tags: java, netbeans

I wrote a java program by netbeans 6.9.1 and jdk 1.6. I don't want to use the output windows of netbeans because it's a bit slow. I am using Windows xp sp3 and I want to run by the cmd. I tried to find in the project **properties -> run** but nothing there. 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you run the project in netbeans it should ask you to pick the main class.  In your case that is already done because there is a value of `sample.Graph` in the `Main Class` field.

Then do a `clean and build` and look at the output window.  It should tell you what `java -jar` command to use to run the program on the command line.

Comment: I known the java -jar command. But I want to call the command prompt and run the program from Netbeans by  click on the run button (F6)

Comment: Well, but in Netbeans for C/C++, it supports what I want.